# Saving file using curl and PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

How can I save a file using curl and PHP?

Comment: are you sure you need curl? is file_get_contents("http://whatever.com") not enough?

Comment: I'm sure over 50% of the 14,000 views did not find that `file_get_contents` was enough

Answer (score 39):

did you want something like this ?

```
function get_file($file, $local_path, $newfilename) 
{ 
    $err_msg = ''; 
    echo "<br>Attempting message download for $file<br>"; 
    $out = fopen($local_path.$newfilename,"wb");
    if ($out == FALSE){ 
      print "File not opened<br>"; 
      exit; 
    } 

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file); 

    curl_exec($ch); 
    echo "<br>Error is : ".curl_error ( $ch); 

    curl_close($ch); 
    //fclose($handle); 

}//end function
```

Functionality:
Its a function and accepts three parameters

```
get_file($file, $local_path, $newfilename)
```

`$file` : is the filename of the object to be retrieved

`$local_path` : is the local path to the directory to store the object

`$newfilename` : is the new file name on the local system

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$out = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);


$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php
and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: This will do the job for small files, but it loads the entire file into memory before saving, and so you will probably hit fatal 'out of memory' errors if the file is larger than PHP's memory limit. Haim Evgi's answer correctly streams the file to disk which avoids this issue.

Comment: I `curl_exec` straight into `file_put_contents()`. At the least, it saves 3 lines of code.

Comment: As in this example, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set before CURLOPT_FILE. The order of the CURLOPT_* is significant  (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082).

Answer (score -6):

I think curl has -o option to write the output to a file instead of stdout.

After -o you have to provide the name of the output file.

example:

```
curl -o path_to_the_file url
```

Comment: This is for the *command-line* version of curl, but not the PHP curl library.