# PHP save image file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

I have an image as a url link from the 3rd party web thumb site (IE http://images.websnapr.com/?size=size&key=Y64Q44QLt12u&url=http://google.com) What I would like to do is run a script that takes the image and saves it in a directory on my server using php. How to do this? would I use File Write?

Comment: For my answer to work your installation of PHP must be compiled with the GD library (most are)...

Comment: See [
saving file using curl
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006604/saving-file-using-curl/1006629#1006629).

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows you how to do this in two ways. http://edmondscommerce.github.io/php/curl/php-save-images-using-curl.html

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No need to create a GD resource, as someone else suggested.

```
$input = 'http://images.websnapr.com/?size=size&key=Y64Q44QLt12u&url=http://google.com';
$output = 'google.com.jpg';
file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
```

Note: this solution only works if you're setup to allow fopen access to URLs. If the solution above doesn't work, you'll have to use cURL.

Comment: What if image format is not jpg. Partially correct answer

Comment: For png 
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng($ouput);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

Answer (score 23):

Note: you should use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693075/1246275) if possible. It's better than mine.

It's quite easy with the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

It's built in usually, you probably have it (use `phpinfo()` to check)

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://images.websnapr.com/?size=size&key=Y64Q44QLt12u&url=http://google.com");

imagejpeg($image, "folder/file.jpg");
```

The above answer is better (faster) for most situations, but with GD you can also modify it in some form (cropping for example).

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://images.websnapr.com/?size=size&key=Y64Q44QLt12u&url=http://google.com");
imagecopy($image, $image, 0, 140, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagejpeg($image, "folder/file.jpg");
```

This only works if [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is `true`  (it is by default)

Comment: This only works if allow_url_fopen is true.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage sure, but by the same token, cURL only works if the curl extension is available and enabled on your system.

Comment: This is forcing GD to decode and encode  the image for no reason.  That also means it's *lossy*, and imagejpeg uses only 75% quality by default.  All the OP asked for is a download (a bit-for-bit copy).