# Save remote file

Tags: php, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP save image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693058/php-save-image-file)

```
$image_url = 'http://site.com/images/image.png';
```

**How do I save file from remote site to my own into some folder?**

Comment: I think someone asks this every day. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+save+remote+file+locally only 34 pages...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
copy($image_url, $your_path);
```

And if `allow_url_fopen`in your php.ini is not set, then get the file with [cURL](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: If file size is too large, try curl method mentioned by Paul Schreiber

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with CURL. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://site.com/images/image.png");
$fp = fopen("image.png", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$image_url = 'http://site.com/images/image.png';
$img = file_get_contents($image_url);
$fp = fopen('image.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $img);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: this puts all data in the RAM before writing it