# image download from another server

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP save image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693058/php-save-image-file)

I want to download images from another server. I have their http path. their is one way that I can download image by right click on it and save this image. but I want to same action with php coding. 
is there any method or any script which help or any idea which is useful in this action.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download & save an image somwhere:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/save/image', file_get_contents($imageurl));
```

Answer (score 0):

php has at least one simple function for that purpose:

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($imageurl);
```