# PHP automatically download file

Tags: php, download

Is it possible to have PHP download a file from a remote server and save it in a local folder?

EDIT

I didn't know this was a duplicate question. Before posting I did search, but was searching for "php automatically download file" and was getting results on how to force a browser to download a file instead of opening it.

Comment: What kind of file. We need to know.

Comment: Oh yeah and it is possible. you know that.

Comment: The file I want to download is a zip file.

Comment: Dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006604/saving-file-using-curl

Comment: I tried searching before I posted but wasn't sure what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <?php
    // set url "http://
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "<your url>"); 

          //return the transfer as a string 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

         // $output contains the output string 
         $output = curl_exec($ch); 

         // close curl resource to free up system resources 
          curl_close($ch); 

    file_put_contents($output,"<file>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).