# Downloading zip file automatically via php code

Tags: php

```
<body>
    <?php
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        if ($zip->open(getcwd() .'/read.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
            $zip->addFile(getcwd() . '/read.txt','/newname.txt');
            $zip->close();


            $file = getcwd() . '/read.zip';
             // http headers for zip downloads
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: public");
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"read.zip\"");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
            readfile($file);

            echo 'ok';

        } else {
            echo 'failed';
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

I have following code and want to download zip file automatically that is being produced by this code when we run this page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP automatically download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151417/php-automatically-download-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to add header for the client about file downloading. just see the manual example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-5315

```
<?php
    $file = getcwd() . '/read.zip';
    // http headers for zip downloads
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"read.zip\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    ob_end_flush();
    @readfile($file);
```

Comment: I have tried the above code. but still its not working. I'm just a beginner. Can u please help me more?

Comment: I have added this headers after $zip->close();

Comment: @Jay, sorry! I've just missed the main thing - readfile($file);

Comment: It generates o/p like........ PK�bFLOm:�/newname.txtHello I'm in reading mode.PK�bFLOm:���/newname.txtPK:Dok........ But not still downloading zip automatically

Comment: just a moment, I'll check it localy

Comment: okay I'm not getting any trouble in downloading text file by adding header().. But here I am getting strange o/p as I mentioned above.

Comment: is the zip file created?

Comment: well, remove the "echo" and try again

Comment: didn't you forget $zip->addFile(getcwd() . '/read.txt',getcwd() . '/newname.txt'); near the newname.txt?

Comment: Yeah I removed echo and tried but still its not working. Even I also add getcwd() before newname.txt but though its not working. It generates the output as I told u before like this..... PK�bFLOm:�3/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Jay/php/exam1/newname.txtHello I'm in reading mode.PK�bFLOm:�3��/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Jay/php/exam1/newname.txtPKak....... as I add getcwd() before newname.txt so it produced newname.txt code in the file as well but not downloading.

Comment: btw I'm using MAC but I don't think that its an OS problem.

Comment: there is an answer for your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411481/php-download-script-creates-unreadable-zip-file-on-mac

Comment: ob_end_flush();
@readfile($file); i've editted the code above

Comment: its still not working.. I have tried all the answers which are in the link which you send. It becomes headache now.

Comment: hey, i didn't notice that you have html code: the body tag. remove it also

Comment: and remove the "echo". and update the main code at the top of the question pls

Comment: yeah! great! ^_^