# Saving photos from link to storage with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5.4

Sorry for newbie question, I used PHP `curl` to store photos in public folder from an external source in my Laravel project. Now I want to store them in storage but I have a hard time to figure it out.

So the question is: How to store photos in storage using `curl`?

This is my code:
//Download photos

```
        mkdir('photos/' . $car->car_id);

        $num = 0;

        foreach (explode('#', $car->pics_urls) as $url)
        {
            $curlCh = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
            $curlData = curl_exec ($curlCh);
            curl_close ($curlCh);

            $downloadPath = 'photos/' . $car->car_id . '/' . ++$num . '.jpg' ;
            $file = fopen($downloadPath, "w+");
            fputs($file, $curlData);
            fclose($file);

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006604/saving-file-using-curl-and-php

Comment: @Vin not exactly what I need,  I know how to save them, what I don't get is how to save them in Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num = 0;
foreach (explode('#', $car->pics_urls) as $url)
{
    $curlCh = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    $curlData = curl_exec ($curlCh);
    curl_close ($curlCh);
    if(!empty($curlData)){
        Storage::disk('local')->put('photos/' . $car->car_id . '/' . ++$num . '.jpg', $curlData);
    }
}
```

Before in head add use Storage;

Comment: almost good only one thing: Why it does not create a folder `. $car->car_id .` ?

Comment: I do not understand.