# How we can download a google docs into our local (computer)/hard drive using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-docs-api

I want to download a google docs in PDF form in my local computer/hard drive after creating it using google docs api with PHP.
For creating google docs I am using using below code from where I can get my document Id which i want to download.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);

$title = 'Demo document';
$document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document([
    "title" => "Test1",
]);

$document = $service->documents->create($document);
$documentId = $document->getdocumentId();
```

and for download this file in my local, I gone through the documentation from this link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221v3DlRiUGic0oUFg3vJmKkZ2PyyG-PJTn0J2nftVtBfo%22%7D#examples , I was using this code -

```
$file = $service->files->get($documentId);
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
```

but I am getting this error -

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Google\Service\Docs::$files in 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function export() on null
```

Can anybody help me through this what mistake I am making and what else I have to do to achieve this.

I also tried like this but it also throwing me the same error-

```
$file = $service->files->export($documentId, 'application/pdf', array(
    'alt' => 'media' ));
$size = $file->getBody()->getSize();
if($size > 0) {
    $content = $file->getBody()->read($size);
}
```

**edited code -**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY,
                        ]);
    // $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory('token.json');
    
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';        
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
       
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path)
{
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$title = 'Demo document';
$document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document([
    "title" => "Test1",
]);
$document = $service->documents->create($document);
$documentId = $document->getdocumentId();
$requests = [];
$index = 1;
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertTable' => [
            'location' => ['index' => $index],
            'columns' => 2,
            'rows' => 2
        ]
    ]),  
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest([
  'requests' => $requests
]);
$result = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);

$documentId = $document->getdocumentId();
$downloadUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=" . $documentId;
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $downloadUrl);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
$file = $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### 1. Add a scope for exporting Google Document as a PDF data.

If you are using the following script,

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS);
```

please modify as follows.

```
$client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS,Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY));
```

When you add the scope, please remove the file including the access token and refresh token, and please authorize the scopes again.I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### 2. Create an URL.

In this case, I think that the exported URL can be created as a string value as follows.

```
$downloadUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=" . $documentId;
```

#### 3. Export Google Document as a PDF file.

From your following script,

```
$request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

I thought that you might use the older version of google-api-php-client. When you are required to use the older version, I think that by the above flow, you can export Google Document as a PDF file.

But, if you update google-api-php-client, in the current version, the following script is used. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/8865cab2efbd63b40f88552886865f31bd7f3edd/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_abstract-classes-have-been-removed)

```
$documentId = "###"; // Please set Document ID. Or when your script is used, please use $documentId = $document->getdocumentId();
$downloadUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=" . $documentId;
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $downloadUrl);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
$file = $response->getBody(); // This is data of the exported PDF data.
```

#### References:

- [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)
- [Google_Auth_Abstract classes have been removed](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/8865cab2efbd63b40f88552886865f31bd7f3edd/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_abstract-classes-have-been-removed)

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but when I just hit the url manually I can see a pdf downloaded in my local but I want it dynamically when I run php quickstart.php it should automatically download my file in my local.But with the above code I cannot verify that as I can only verify it by hitting the url manually.Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I am using "composer require google/apiclient:^2.12.1" this version of library.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. About `but when I just hit the url manually I can see a pdf downloaded in my local but I want it dynamically when I run php quickstart.php it should automatically download my file in my local.`, I have already proposed it in my answer like `Please set Document ID. Or when your script is used, please use $documentId = $document->getdocumentId();`. I thought that this might be the result you expect. I apologize for this.

Comment: I am doing like this only.$documentId = $document->getdocumentId();
$downloadUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=" . $documentId;
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $downloadUrl);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
$file = $response->getBody();

Comment: but it is not downlaoding that file in my local automatically.What am i missing.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I tested your showing script, a new Google Document is created and the Document is exported as a PDF file. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `but it is not downlaoding that file in my local automatically.`. I apologize for this. In your situation, an error occurs when you run the script? By the way, as I have mentioned in my answer, you add a scope of `Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY` and reauthorize the scopes?

Comment: I added the same scope you have mentioned and also reauthorized it. I have edited my question under "edited code" section and shown u how i am doing , Can you now identify what am i missing?Please check once.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying and adding your script. I think that your script has no issue. Can I ask you about your current issue? For example, when you save the exported PDF data as a file by putting `file_put_contents("sample.pdf", $file);` to the last line of your script, what result will you obtain?

Comment: when I added the line you have mentioned at the last it created a file in my quickstart.php file path as "sample.pdf".But i wanted to name it as the title of my document.It just created a file , it is not behaving as downloading type.

Comment: @Taniya Halder In that case, please use `file_put_contents($title . ".pdf", $file);`

Comment: it shows me  Permission denied error. I can't give permissions to every file 
 I create.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242101/discussion-between-taniya-halder-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2):

File export method is part of the google drive api not the google docs api. You need to create a drive service object you have created a docs service object.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file = $service->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array(
        'alt' => 'media' ));
    $size = $file->getBody()->getSize();
    if($size > 0) {
        $content = $file->getBody()->read($size);
    }
```

The files now are in $content you just need to write it to a file

```
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Comment: @DalmTo, I went through your answer.With this I didn't got any error but the thing is I cannot see any file being downloaded in my local how can I verify that.

Comment: the consents of the file are in $content.   Just save it. use file_put_contents.  I edited my anwser.

Comment: @dalmto, i don't want to use file_put_contents, I want it with using CURL. Is it possible with this?

Comment: your code is PHP why switch to curl?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006629/1841839 theres a bunch of examples on stack https://stackoverflow.com/q/6177661/1841839